# Change the SQL request of report

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I'm creating a report using the Crystal Report for Visual Studio 2010 but I dont know how to change the SQL request.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean, "change the SQL request"?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can directly change any SQL that Crystal Reports generates.

If you want to control the query yourself, you can perform your own query first and pass in your DataSet to Crystal Reports.

Answer (score 0):

good

I tried to change the sql request but we can not change it after the creation of the report by cons at the time of creation using the wizzard we can selects new command, and at this level we introduce our request.

Thanks again.